# Node.JS callback function, listen input object event

Tags: node.js, callback

Following is a standard Node.js http get request. In the callback function, we listen response 'data' and 'end' event. 
 
My question is: what if the response data event fired before the callback execution? It seems possible to me.

```
var request = http.get(option, function(res) {
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            var data = "";
            res.on('data', function(d) {
                data += d
            });

            res.on('end', function() {
                ...
            });
        });
```

Comment: I can't understand how it is possible.

Comment: @o_nix when the callback fires, there is already a response object, that means it has some bit, so the data event may fired before. I'm confused about the execution flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`res` is just an instance of the [**http.ClientResponse**](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_http_clientresponse) class that *[magically](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/3c293ba27250f1885efa8d8db8e75d3ea033c206/lib/http.js#L1183)* [comes](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/3c293ba27250f1885efa8d8db8e75d3ea033c206/lib/http.js#L1483) into the callback [right after](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/3c293ba27250f1885efa8d8db8e75d3ea033c206/lib/http.js#L111) response headers processing and strictly before the HTTP response body.